# Is there a way to know the options of a shell/terminal command/application?

Tags: macos, shell, configuration, terminal, customization

What I would like to know is, if there is any way to get the options used by a command or application (having no manual entry.  For example:

For the application *ScreenSaverEngine*, located in:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

has the option *-background* which allows me to set the current screensaver as a desktop background.

```
./ScreenSaverEngine -background
```

Now I would like to do other stuff with this application, or at least I would like to know if there is a possibility to do other stuff. So I want to know all the other options of *ScreenSaverEngine*. I thought maybe some options are coded in the app, so I tried something like

```
strings ScreenSaverEngine | grep "-"
```

but without results. *ScreenSaverEngine* doesn't have a manual, so

```
man ScreenSaverEngine
```

won't help. I'd be happy for any suggestions :-).

(By the way I'm using MAC OS X).

Comment: `-h`, `--help`, `-help`, `-?` are some of the common switches to list the help information provided by the application.

Comment: no, and I gave up trying theses, cause any option not support would launch the Screensaver :-/

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation in Apple's Developer area - searching for [ScreenSaver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/) here came up with 4 useful looking documents for me.

Comment: I couldn't find a reference of ScreenSaverEngine, nevertheless this site is awesome -> I ll start writing my first Mac app :-). Thanks Jonathan.

Comment: Just a little follow up: The full path is not necessary, some ``open -a ScreenSaverEngine.app --args -background`` works fine on my machine.. To stop it, use something like this: ``pkill -x ScreenSaverEngine``.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any arbitrary application, this is not possible, because the `argv` parameters passed to the program's `main()` function (in C) can be stored, parsed, and accessed any way the program wants. It could even write the parameters out to a file, and then read the file when it wants to know what options to use.

However, it looks like the command-line options are already documented.
From [CocoaDev](http://cocoadev.github.io/ScreenSaverEngine/):

> The ScreenSaverEngine supports some special command line flags to aid
>   in debugging:
>
> -background -- All screen saver windows appear behind all other windows (behind Finder icons but in front of the desktop image). The
>   password and gamma fade features are disabled. It will not exit on
>   mouse or keyboard activity.
>
> -debug -- Like -background, except mouse movement over the desktop causes it to exit. Very handy when running the ScreenSaverEngine in
>   GDB. (Trying to get around my computer in this mode without causing it
>   to exit reminds me of playing Don't Touch The Floor as a kid)
>
> -module  -- Loads the specified module rather than the module specified by the user defaults.  accepts the same values as the moduleName node in ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.*.plist For
>   example, Flurry, Abstract, or Spectrum. It doesn't appear to accept
>   full paths or URLs to .saver, .slideSaver, or .qtz files, however, so
>   it's necessary to place the desired module in one of the typical
>   ScreenSaver folders and reference it without the filename extension.

-window -- an additional command runs the screensaver in a window.

> this can be combined with -background. example: -window -background

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the accuracy of the result. But it makes logical sense.

I went ahead and looked to answer this question because apple broke the 
-background flag with High Sierra. Still an issue as of High Sierra 10.13.4

This was from my mac running Sierra 10.12.16 the executable is the same but it is in a different file location for HighSierra.

So to get this working. The ScreenSaverEngine is an executable file.

Strings is a command that clumps anything that looks like english.
I need to cat the file to get a string output because by default it is reads as binary and does not give any result.

```
cat /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine | strings
```

I manually looked through the files but your could add this to see the files I eventually noticed:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine | strings | grep /System
```

Then I noticed that the program was calling this Versions/A/ScreenSaver

```
cat /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/ScreenSaver | strings
```

I manually looked through and spotted an Arguments section.

payoff:
arguments

- -idleCheck
- -cornerCheck
- -debug
- -window
- ss-windowed-mode=1
- -numWindows
- -background
- -foreground
- -loginWindow
- -mainOnly
- -module
- -lockDelay
- floatValue
- -black
- -noEarlyMouseCheck
- argument '%@' not understood
- Background mode is disabled because full screen application was
  detected.

no idea why there is not official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script I like to put in my path:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo "usage: $0 [options]"
    echo "  -background  Screen saver windows appear behind all other windows"
    echo "  -debug       Like -background, except mouse movement over the"
    echo "                 desktop causes it to exit"
    echo "  -module      Loads the specified module by name"
}

engine=/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources\
/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine

while getopts "hbackgrounddebugmodule" opt; do
    case "${opt}" in
        h)
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
    esac
done

$engine "$@"
```